# Updating Google Spreadsheet Row by Row using Gspread

Tags: json, api, gspread

I am using Python and gspread to insert data into/update my Google spreadsheet.

I have tried two different scripts. The first gives me the error that the object is not JSON serializable. The second works but eventually stops because I reach my quota of API calls. I have a lot of data that needs to be updated.

Code 1

```
    row=list(df.iloc[i])
    sheet.insert_row(row, i+2)
```

Code 2

```
    row=list(df1.iloc[i])
    for j in range(len(row)):
        x = str(row[j])
        sheet.update_cell(i+2,j+1,x)
```

Error 1

```
TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For your situation, as a method, I would like to recommend to use [``update_cells()``](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_cells#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells). But from your script, I cannot correctly understand about your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. So can you provide a sample value of ``row`` and the information of ``i``. From them, I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I want to update a 8x8 dataframe of date and numeric string into the Google Sheet. I would like to find a way to update the whole table at once, instead of cell by cell.

I have also tried the method in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447671/adding-rows-on-a-spreadsheet-exceeds-100-sec-user-quota?rq=1 but it gives me the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. If I take the decode part out, I then get the error 'list index out of range'. Apologies - I am still very new to Python.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your additional information, I couldn't understand about your situation for resolving your issue. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is the row number in this case.

```
     n_rows, n_cols = df.shape
     for i in range(n_rows):
         row_values = list(df.iloc[i])

         # if you want to insert the value of the row at the index i
         sheet.insert_row(row_values,i)
```